# Getting directory listing in Cake build script

Tags: cakebuild

Is there a simple method for getting a directory listing (e.g., DirectoryPathCollection) for a given directory path?

I'd like to be able to get all directories easily for the current directory as well as from a given path.

I'm not seeing anything obvious in [Directory Operations reference](http://cakebuild.net/dsl/directory-operations/), nor in [DirectoryPath](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core.IO/DirectoryPath/) or [DirectoryAliases](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.IO/DirectoryAliases/).

### Workarounds

So far, I've found a couple approaches that do work.

Using the `GlobbingAliases.GetDirectories` method with an argument to match all, but that seems like a bit of a hack. (It also has some quirks for trying to get sub-directories, but that is going to be a separate issue I'll investigate.)

```
var allDirectories = GetDirectories(@".\*");
```

Additionally, I have had luck just going directly to `System.IO.Directory` methods.

```
var allDirectories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(".", "*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Select (d => new DirectoryPath(d));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Context.FileSystem](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core.IO/IFileSystem/) it has a [GetDirectory](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core.IO/IFileSystem/486B88E5) it returns a [IDirectory](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core.IO/IDirectory/) which has a [GetDirectories](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core.IO/IDirectory/2AF24215) method.

The advantage of using Cake's abstractions is that i.e modules can supply alternative implementations i.e long path support on system that don't support that with regular .Net

Comment: Short of reading the source, is there a reference/guide for that `GetDirectories` method's `filter` parameter? Even a usage example there might be helpful.

Comment: Additionally, when should one be using `IDirectory` vs. `DirectoryPath`? Should all the places I use `DirectoryPath` be rewritten to target `IDirectory`?

Comment: IDirectory is "low level" , you'll mostly be using the globber GetDirectories and DirectoryPath which is what most aliases use for parameters too.